# Why does redirection in pipelines behave differently in Bash and Zsh?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, zsh, io-redirection

Redirection behaves differently in Bash and Zsh when hooked up to a pipe:

```
bash> echo foo >/dev/null | cat
bash>
```

```
zsh> echo foo >/dev/null | cat
foo
zsh>
```

Bash does what I expect; in Zsh, the STDOUT redirected to `/dev/null` seems to come back from the dead.

Why this difference? What's going on in each case?

Answer (score 7):

Zsh has a fancy feature called [multios](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios). If you turn it off, the behavior will be almost identical to Bash.

```
% echo a >/dev/null | cat
a
% set +o multios          
% echo a >/dev/null | cat
%
```

And this is documented in the manual as follows.

> Note that a pipe is an implicit redirection; thus[, when *multios* is on, and it is on by default]
>
> ```
> date >foo | cat
> ```
>
> writes the date to the file `foo`, and also pipes it to `cat`.